# How to keep original values of cells if they do not meet criterion in case when at R?

Tags: r, case-when

I want the mutate to run on all cells values (edited: in DF with multiple columns), and if it doesn't meet any criterion of the case_when, to keep the original data.
for example
mutate(~case_when(.=="hi" ~1,
.=="hello"~2,
T~(keep original value)
))

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running `case_when` only for 1 column you can refer to the column name itself in `TRUE ~`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(cyl = case_when(col == 'hi' ~ 1, 
                         col == 'hello' ~ 2, 
                         TRUE ~ col))
```

If you are running this for multiple columns with `mutate_at`/`across` you can use `.`

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(a, b), ~case_when(.== "hi" ~ 1, 
                                    .== "hello"~2, 
                                    TRUE ~ .)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have multiple columns, around 85, so across by vector is too much... Any other way to do it?

Comment: @iftachs How are the columns arranged? 1) You can use numbers (eg - `1:85`, `3:87`). 2) Can use pattern in column names (eg - `starts_with('abc')`, `ends_with('abc')`. 3) Can use range of columns (eg `A:Z`).